# Calling a script (with no extension) in Windows to compile code

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-construction, cmake, call

I'm a complete newbie when it comes to this, apologies if this appears retarded - been searching for a while with no avail.

I have file in a folder called "quocGCC" and to compile the code I have to go into this directory and call the script called "go" (it has no extension).

**THIS is where I'm stuck (embarrassing, I know), so how exactly do I call this script in windows?**

I've been told that this invokes cmake with all necessary options and will create makefiles (cmake is installed), not sure about the GCC compiler (is this necessary to install or can I do with another compiler?).

Thank you very much in advance,

Peter

Comment: Do you know what type of script you have?  Windows generally hides the extensions of known file types, but some scripts (particularly Linux scripts) don't always have extensions.  You can usually open it up and view the top line for a clue.  If it starts with something like #bin/bash it is usually designed to run on Linux / Cygwin.  You might be able to double click the file to run it.  You may be able to run it from the command line (start, run, type: cmd, then use CD to get to the directory, then type the name of the script).  It may be designed to run in a Linux environment as well.

Comment: @Jonathan, it turns out that the code I received was for linux! Thank you for your comment. Hopefully I'll get some windows code soon.

Comment: You can download Cygwin (basically a Linux emulator) to run on your Windows machine if needed.  I made quite a bit of use of that back in my college days.